# Input box - Prevent user from entering 0 as first digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input boxes. I want that user should not be able to enter any digit which starts with 0. Note that only 0 at the beginning. It can be at the end or middle but not at the beginning.

So allow 4, 40, 4440 but not 04.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBFqZ/8/) where I've put several other restrictions like only numeric values are allowed, length is 4. Now I want to add the restriction related to 0.

How can this be done using jQuery?

**HTML**

```
<input name="major" size="1" value="4" class="major_rev">.

<input name="minor" size="1" value="24" class="minor_rev">
```

Comment: Only test on `keyup`, not on `keydown`, and use a simple regex (something like `/^[1-9]\d*$/`)

Comment: Are you aware that you don't allow people to use the fields with a numpad?

Comment: If I use `keyup` then the check for `don't allow alphabets` doesn't work.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak if you have solved your issue with one of the below id like to know which one :D maybe mark one? or if you want with a totally different answer maybe you can add that and mark it as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing values in html inputs with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297547/preventing-values-in-html-inputs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sangram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18123828/257635) and [miklshake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18123943/257635)'s answers helped me. Below is the combined solution.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.major_rev', function(event){

    var input = event.currentTarget.value;

    if(input.search(/^0/) != -1){
         alert("you have started with a 0");   
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    //For numeric
    $(".major_rev").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything

        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((event.keyCode !==9) && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
                else{

              if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
            {
                if(event.keyCode == 48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }

            }
        }
    });
    $(".minor_rev").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            if($.trim($(this).val()).length==0)
            {
                if(event.keyCode==48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
            else{

              if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
            {
                if(event.keyCode == 48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }
            }
        }
    });
    //For MaxLength
    $(".major_rev").prop("maxlength","4");
    $(".minor_rev").prop("maxlength","4");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBFqZ/12/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gBFqZ/10/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //For numeric
    $(".major_rev").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything

        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((event.keyCode !==9) && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
                else{

              if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
            {
                if(event.keyCode == 48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }

            }
        }
    });
    $(".minor_rev").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            if($.trim($(this).val()).length==0)
            {
                if(event.keyCode==48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
            else{

              if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
            {
                if(event.keyCode == 48){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                }
            }
            }
        }
    });
    //For MaxLength
    $(".major_rev").prop("maxlength","4");
    $(".minor_rev").prop("maxlength","4");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this solution if I enter `4000` and then remove `4` from beginning then I'm able to create scenario with `0` at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

how about using this simple check:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#testBox', function(event){

    var input = event.currentTarget.value;

    if(input.search(/^0/) != -1){
         alert("you have started with a 0");   
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgBBv/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of late  but try this easy and simple

```
$(".major_rev").on("keyup", function () {               
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
  $(this).val(null);                                     
  }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we are looking at regular expressions here..

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if( val.indexOf("0") == 0 ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("placeholder", "Invalid");
    }
});
```