# How to prevent a zero or negative number being typed in a number input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

This question has been asked for negative numbers but all answers still have the ability to add a `0`. When ordering a product on my shop and setting the quantity to `0` you can place the order with no costs so the minimal number should be `1`.

I thought maybe I can disable the `0` from being typed using javascript (this works for negative numbers by preventing a dash from being typed) but what if someone types `10`? So I need another solution.

How can I do this?

My input field:

```
<input name="quantity" id="'.$cart['productid'].$cart['kuubkosten'].'" value="'.$cart['quantity'].'" type="number" min="1">
```

Comment: You already have `min="1"` so the form will not be submitted if a `0` is entered. You don't need anything more client-side, but server-side you should be checking the value is valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123438/input-box-prevent-user-from-entering-0-as-first-digit

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It is submitted with the 0 or negative numbers probably because I am using ajax.

Comment: @twan Because you are not using the event `onsubmit`

Comment: @twan Check my answer once it can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preventing User inputting 0 or negative**

The below code will prevent user from inputting 0 or negative values

```js
let qty = document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']");
qty.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    if (this.value < 1) this.value = 1; // minimum is 1
    else this.value = Math.floor(this.value); // only integers allowed
})
```

```html
<input name="quantity" id="dummyId" value="0" type="number" min="1">
```

If you don't want to bother with too much javascript, the following is a more concise way to do it:

```html
<input name="quantity" id="dummyId" value="0" type="number" min="1" onchange="this.value = Math.floor(Math.max(this.value,1))">
```

You can remove the `Math.floor()` bit if you don't care about rounding to integers.

Comment: The problem is not exactly people not having anything when they visit the page, but people being able to edit the quantity below 1. I can still write `0` or `-10` with above code in that input field and update the price resulting in `€0,-` or even a negative price.

Comment: Thank you this works the first time but after I update the product summary and update again the code is not applied anymore (I get the updated elements with ajax). But I think I can fix that myself, for my question this answer works, thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome! If necessary, you may want to replace `document.querySelectorAll` with the more precise `document.getElementById($cart['productid'].$cart['kuubkosten'])` which will target the input's unique `id`

Comment: Also added a concise form of `<input>` if you don't want to bother with `<script></script>`

Comment: Thanks, this also fixed my ajax issue since I now just added that line in both files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following onchange to authorize only positive integer greater than equal 1 :

```
<input type="number"  onchange="this.value = Math.max(Math.ceil(Math.abs(this.value || 1)) || 1);">
```

But value can still be edited/transformed with javascript, don't forget to realize the real control on your backend

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do something like this, I also got this kind of issue someday's back then i came up with this solution

Give a `class` name to your input field and `type=tel` it will work with `number` also but it is taking `minus` so i had to use `tel`

```
<input name="quantity" id="'.$cart['productid'].$cart['kuubkosten'].'" value="'.$cart['quantity'].'" type="class="test" >
```

Than do like below

```
(function($) {
          $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
            return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
              if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
                this.oldValue = this.value;
                this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
                this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
              } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                this.value = this.oldValue;
                this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
              }
            });
          };
        }(jQuery));

     $(".test").inputFilter(function(value) {


         return /^\d*[.]?\d*$/.test(value);
         });
```

function will check the values entered inside the input field,than on your input field filter you can use `RegExp` to allow waht type of input you want

**Working Snippet**

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

$(".test").inputFilter(function(value) {


  return /^\d*[.]?\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quantity" id="'.$cart['productid'].$cart['kuubkosten'].'" value="'.$cart['quantity'].'" type="tel" class="test">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an onChange function to the input:

```
const onChange = (event) => {
   if(event.target.value <= 0) {
       event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: I placed above code in an `onChange` but it's not working.

Comment: This code is re-inventing the `min="1"` attribute that OP *already has*.